# $HOME/.Wolfram Directory on Linux

Tags: documentation, linux, installation

Simply asking since I have not been able to find an answer anywhere else.
How can I move the directory `$HOME/.Wolfram`, I have not been able to find any documentation mentioning it yet whenever Mathematica is opened it is recreated.

I have had success with moving '`$HOME/.Mathematica`' and similarly with '`Documents/Wolfram Mathematica`' but no such luck with `$HOME/.Wolfram`